# No such file or directory: 'FirebaseCrashlytics' in ui tests target

Tags: swift, xcode, crashlytics, xcode-ui-testing

I need help.

I have a project with 3 targets: General, UnitTests, and UITests.
I have FirebaseCrashlytics in my project.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform: ios, '14.5'


target 'AppName' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  
  # Pods for AppName
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

  
  target 'AppNameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    use_frameworks!
    # Pods for testing
    
  end
  
  target 'AppNameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
end
```

When I started tests, I got an error: No such file or directory: 'FirebaseCrashlytics'.
[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl5Da.png)

My general target started well and work, I have problems only started tests.

I have scripts in General Target.
[Crashlytics scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qXfR.png)

I try reinstalling pods and try add crashlytics scripts in the ui tests target.